# How to access props.match.params in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to access the handle ID which is set up on my App.js like this:

```
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/users/:handle' component={User}/>
            </Switch>
           </Router>
```

I want to access it in my User component, but am getting the error "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined". How do you access the match params in a functional component?

```
const User = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {
  getProfile();
})

const getProfile = (props) => {
    const { handle } = props.match.params.handle;
    const { postId } = props.match.params.postId;

    if (postId) setPostIdParam(postId);

    props.getUserData(handle);
    axios.get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProfile(res.data.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: https://learnwithparam.com/blog/dynamic-pages-in-react-router/

Comment: It appears that you are using `getProfile` as an arrow function within the `User` component? Try replacing `(props)` with `()` if that is the case, because right now it looks like you are assigning the parameter of `getProfile` to overwrite the `User` props. This is likely a scoping issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `props` to the function as you've defined it. The function `getProfile` has a locally scoped variable named `props`.

```
const User = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile(props); // <-- pass the component props
  })

  const getProfile = (props) => { // <-- function takes props object!!
    const { handle, postId } = props.match.params;

    if (postId) setPostIdParam(postId);

    props.getUserData(handle);
    axios.get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProfile(res.data.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Alternatively, remove `props` from the function signature and use the one defined int he functional component scope instead.

```
const User = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  })

  const getProfile = () => {
    const { handle, postId } = props.match.params; // <-- component props object!!
    
    if (postId) setPostIdParam(postId);

    props.getUserData(handle);
    axios.get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProfile(res.data.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Unless your props really has `handle` nested in `props.match.params.handle` and same for `postId`, I think you meant to either

```
const handle = props.match.params.handle;
const postId = props.match.params.postId;
```

Or use object destructuring better

```
const { handle, postId } = props.match.params;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, I noticed there was an error in how you were destructuring `params`

```
const User = (props) => {
  const { handle, postId } = props.match.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  });

  const getProfile = (props) => {
    if (postId) setPostIdParam(postId);

    props.getUserData(handle);
    axios.get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProfile(res.data.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```